# How to consistently make the background be blue in assembly for DOS/BIOS/VGA

Tags: assembly, background-color, x86-16

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    num db 3
    msg1 db 13,10, 'Enter the size of the Square [1-9]: $'
         db 1Fh
    msg2 db 13,10, 'Do you want to try again? [y/n]: $'
         db 1Fh
    msg3 db 13,10, 'No Square to display. $'
         db 1Fh

.code
main    proc

    mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax
        mov es,ax

        mov ah, 0
        mov al, 3

   get_input: int 10h

    mov ah, 6
        mov al, 0
    mov bh, 00010000b 
        mov cx, 0
        mov dx, 184FH
        int 10h
    
        mov ah, 09h
        mov dx, offset msg1
    int 21h

        mov ah, 01h
        int 21h 
        sub al, '0'    
        mov cl, al
        mov bx, 0

        cmp al, 0
        je no_square
        cmp al, 1
        je no_square

        mov ah, 02h
        mov dl, 0ah
        int 21h
        jmp outerloop_top

  no_square:
        mov ah, 09h
        mov dx, offset msg3  ; 'No Square to display' message
        int 21h
        jmp tryAgain

    outerloop_top:
        mov ch, cl
        mov bh, 1

    outerloop_rows:
        cmp bh, ch
        jg outerloop_exit
        mov bl, 1

        innerloop_columns:
            cmp bl, cl
            jg innerloopexit_top
            mov dl, '*'
            mov ah, 02h
            int 21h
            mov dl, ''
            mov ah, 02h
            int 21h
            inc bl
            jmp innerloop_columns

        innerloopexit_top:
        mov dl, 0dh
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h
        mov dl, 0ah
        int 21h
        inc bh
        jmp outerloop_rows

    outerloop_exit:
        jmp tryAgain

    tryAgain:
        mov ah,09h
        mov dx, offset msg2 ; 'Do you want to try again? [y/n]:' message
        int 21h
        mov ah,01h
        int 21h
        cmp al, 59h

        je get_input
        cmp al, 79h
    
        je get_input
        jmp exit

    exit:
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21H
        int 20h

main    endp
end main
```

problem with the background color to stay blue, because after a few repetitions it goes to black background and white foreground. Like if user repeats the code a few more times it would go back to the default background and foreground.

I tried following something in Youtube and it made the foreground blue and background black and a lot of hearts appeared.
I expect every display to a background of color blue.

Comment: use, the function that prints char + attribute (color) and set it to be blue for the bits of the background. This way it will print the text plus not erase it (re-print). I guess another option would be to put chars directly into memory, and skip every second char not to destroy the attribs.

Comment: I've checked the code and in this case, you could just set the cursor position to be top-left corner after you've scrolled up the window. This way you would end up in the same spot as you start with.

Answer (score 2):

### Some review first

> ```
>   mov ah, 0
>   mov al, 3
> get_input: int 10h  (1)
>
>   ...
>
>   cmp al, 59h
>   je get_input
>   cmp al, 79h
>   je get_input
>   jmp exit           (2)
> exit:
>   mov ah,4ch
>   int 21H
>   int 20h            (3)
> ```

(1) The `int 10h` instruction belongs to setting the video mode. You should have placed it above the *get_input* label. Currently it is a lucky (?) coincidence that the AH register happens to hold 01h when the code jumps to *get_input* after confirmation by the user. That way the only harm was a silly setting of the cursor shape to a very thin line (because by then CH and CL are equal to each other with a value in the range [2,9]).
(2) The `jmp exit` is redundant as the execution would have continued at the *exit* label anyway.
(3) The `int 20h` is redundant as it will never get executed. The program was already terminated by the 4Ch function.

### Scrolling is the culprit

Whenever DOS makes the screen scroll, it uses the default character attribute again, so WhiteOnBlack. With an installable console driver like ANSI.SYS you could get DOS to use some other setting. From the commandline you could then issue a command like: `prompt $e[30;44m$p$g`. In theory this will work, in practice not so much! Often I have witnessed the return of the default WhiteOnBlack attribute. Short story, I have abandoned ANSI.SYS a long time ago.

The solution for *your* program is simple. **Just never allow scrolling to happen**. Each time the user confirms that they want to try again, put the cursor in the upper left corner of the screen and continue from there. Alternatively and shorter in code size, you could reset the video mode and paint it blue again.

```
  mov  ax, 0003h
  int  10h          ; BIOS.SetVideoMode 3
get_input:
  xor  dx, dx
  mov  bh, 0
  mov  ah, 02h      ; BIOS.SetCursorPosition (0,0)
  int  10h

  mov ax, 0600h     ; BIOS.PaintRectangle (0,0)-(79,24)
  mov bh, 00010000b ; BlackOnBlue
  mov cx, 0
  mov dx, 184Fh
  int 10h

  ...

    
tryAgain:
  mov  ah, 09h
  mov  dx, offset msg2 ; 'Do you want to try again? [y/n]:' message
  int  21h
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  21h
  cmp  al, 'Y'
  je   get_input
  cmp  al, 'y'
  je   get_input
exit:
  mov  ah, 4C00h
  int  21H
```